# Проблемы с GlobalKey или маршрутом в проекте flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Пишу приложения на flutter но сталкнулься стакой ситуацией. использея реализацию роутера таким образом, мне очень подходит но есть некая проблема.. когда я запускаю проект в браузере на локальном сервере  то все работает как надо я перехожу по ссылкам.. меняю адресс в ручную в адресной строке браузера. вобщем все работает, но если я перезагружу станицу. то все ломается. красный экран ошибки  ══╡╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list.

The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building _FocusInheritedScope:
Expected a value of type 'Handler', but got one of type 'Null'

конечно есть другой вариант исрользовать простой routes  и писать деревянныйм способом, явные маршруты /home/agent   /home/client  но это пока мне не понадовится айди клиента . и мне опять придется подстраиваться или искать обходные пути

Another exception was thrown: A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list.

я перепробовал 100 вариантов исправить это даже обратился к ии .. но ничего не помогло

```js
class AppRouter {
  static final FluroRouter router = FluroRouter();
 
 
  static void setupRouter() {
    // Уникальные ключи для каждого маршрута
    router.define(
      '/',
      handler: Handler(handlerFunc: (_, __) => FirebaseStream()),
      transitionType: TransitionType.fadeIn,
    );

    router.define(
      '/first',
      handler: Handler(handlerFunc: (_, __) => ScreenLoader(loadScreen: () async => PublicControllerGeneral().firstPage())),
      transitionType: TransitionType.fadeIn,
    );

    router.define(
      '/verification',
      handler: Handler(handlerFunc: (_, __) => ScreenLoader(loadScreen: () async => PublicControllerGeneral().firstPage())),
      transitionType: TransitionType.fadeIn,
    );

router.define(
  '/home/:userType',
  handler: Handler(handlerFunc: (context, params) {
   final userType = params['userType']?.first;
  
    return ScreenLoader(
      loadScreen: () async => PublicControllerGeneral().homePage(userType), // Передаем ValueKey в PublicControllerGeneral().homePage()
    );
  }),
  transitionType: TransitionType.fadeIn,
);



  }
}
```